# Scala: filtering list of tuples to get a nonEmptyList

Tags: scala, scala-cats

I have a list of the type `List[(A, List[B])]`. I want to flatten this structure and get:

- `NonEmptyList[A]` consisting of all the `A`corresponding to a nonEmpty `List[B]`.
- all those `B`s combined: `NonEmptyList[B]`

ie, I want to get `Option[(NonEmptyList[A], NonEmptyList[B])]`. What is the most concise way of doing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Untested, but using definitions from the comments, this should work:

```
for {
  a <- NonEmptyList.fromList(list.collect{ case (a, _::_) => a })
  b <- NonEmptyList.fromList(list.flatMap(_._2))
} yield (a, b)
```

This also has the advantage of avoiding the second computation if the first returns `None`.

---

Previous versions:

```
val listA = list.collect{ case (a, _::_) => a }
val listB = list.flatMap(_._2)

listA.headOption.flatMap(listB.headOption.map(_ => (NonEmptyList(listA), NonEmptyList(listB))))
```

Another version might be

```
(listA, listB) match {
  case (_::_, _::_) =>
    Some(NonEmptyList(listA), NonEmptyList(listB))
  case _ =>
    None
}
```

Comment: NonEmptyList's constructor takes a head and a tail. Alternatively it also has a fromList function that gives you an Option[NonEmptyList]

Comment: Ahh... the formulation at the top looks great. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could just iterate over the list with tail-recursive function, but it's probably not very concise, but it might be faster than the second solution because it iterates just once over the list.

```
def flat[A,B](list: List[(A, List[B])]): Option[(NonEmptyList[A], NonEmptyList[B])] = {

    @tailrec
    def collapse(list: List[(A, List[B])], as: List[A], bs: List[B]): (List[A], List[B]) = {
      list match {
        case (a,b) :: xs => collapse(xs, a :: as, b ++ bs)
        case Nil => (as, bs)
      }
    }

    collapse(list, Nil, Nil) match {
      case (a :: ax, b :: bx) => Some((NonEmptyList(a, ax), NonEmptyList(b, bx)))
      case _ => None
    }

}
```

Another option is to use `unzip`:

```
def flat2[A,B](list: List[(A, List[B])]) = list.unzip match {
   case (as,bs) => (as, bs.flatten)  match {
      case (a :: ax, b :: bx) => Some((NonEmptyList(a, ax), NonEmptyList(b, bx)))
      case _ => None
   }
}
```

Result:

```
flat(List((1, List("a", "b")), (2, List("a", "c")), (3, List("d", "e")), (4, List("x", "y"))))
//Some((NonEmptyList(4, 3, 2, 1),NonEmptyList(x, y, d, e, a, c, a, b)))
flat(List((1, List()), (2, List("a"))))
//Some((NonEmptyList(2, 1),NonEmptyList(a)))
flat(List((1, List()), (2, List())))
//None
flat(List())
//None
```

Comment: I don't think you are applying this test: "`NonEmptyList[A]` consisting of all the `A` 
 **corresponding to a nonEmpty `List[B]`**"

Comment: Yes, I don't get it to be honest. Does it mean A should only contain values also in B?

Comment: @KrzysztofAtłasik let's say A is a person and B is a car. the original list, is a list of people mapped to the cars they own. I want to get a list of all drivers and all the cars they own.

Comment: Can you add an example test case in your question? For example, let's say your input is `(List((1, List("a", "b")), (2, List("a", "c")), (3, List("d", "e")), (4, List("x", "y"))))`. What would be youtr desired output? Would order matter?

Comment: @Tim And in this case `None` should be returned? `flat(List((1, List(), (2, List(2))))` evaluates to `None`?